# In python, how to import just words but not any punctuation from a .txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

For example ,I have a txt file which content is:

> Blockquote

```
star, year, op, ed
ad, ed, offer, year
```

> Blockquote

I want to import them and form a list which have each line as a sublist:
    [['star','year','op','ed'],['ad','ed','offer','year']]
So I use the command below:

> Blockquote

```
list = []
with open ("file_name", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        split_line = line.split()
        list.append(split_line)
f.close()
```

But when I print the list, the result is:

> Blockquote

```
[['star,','year,','op,','ed'],['ad,','ed,','offer,','year']]
```

So how can I get a list with only words but not any punctuations?

Comment: please properly format your code as code. It's a single click on the "code formatting" button, labelled `{}`.

Comment: If you don't want to include the commas, why don't you include them in what you `.split` on? Or just use `csv`?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is splitting with comma and space:

```
with open ("file_name") as f:
    result = [line.split(', ') for line in f]
```

And note that you don't need to close the file manually when you are using `whith` statement. That's exactly what the `with` does at the end of the block. And another note, don't name your variable names with python built-in names.

As another alternative (and more pythonic approach) for this task you can use `csv` module which will split your lines automatically with a delimiter (by default the comma).

```
import csv
with open ("file_name") as f:
    spam_reader = csv.reader(f) # you can pass the delimiter to reader function (if its something else rather than comma)
    rows = list(spam_reader)
```

Answer (score 0):

in split function try to give ", " as argument like this.

```
split_line = line[:-2].split(", ")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This not work since the last item of every line does not have ", "

Comment: I guess it should be working as there no need to have ", " at the end of line. Tried this?

Comment: yes, I've tried, but for the last item of each line, in the list it will be represented as something like "year/n" but not "year"

Comment: Most welcome. Mark it as correct to approve this.  :)